# Check if strings are in a correct pattern and distinguish them

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm making a win application for homework which load quadratic or linear equations from a text file. I have 2 formats: `ax^2 + bx + c = 0` or `ax + b = 0`

My problem is that I need to distinguish if it is quadratic or linear and check if they are in a correct format but I have problem with string pattern, came up with something like this but it doesn't work

```
string pattern = @"?([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\w{1}[^2])([+-][0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+\w{1})([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+ \=[0]);
```

Because I don't understand regex that much I would like to ask you if you can help me with string pattern which will optionally match 1st part in format (+-, float number, char^2)  then 2nd part (+-, float number, char) and last part (+-, float number, = 0)

Comment: Understanding Regex can be a challenge.  Especially for people like me that don't use it regularly enough to be proficient at it.  I always use this page to help me build and test my RegEx expressions:  [Online RegEx](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah, in the end i used that dotNET ´s solution, but made mistake by thanking in the answer so they deleted it. But all answers here was great and helped me a lot in understanding this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on the following lines will detect quadratic equations for you. It is not 100% fail-safe, but should work in most cases:

```
[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?(?<var>\w)\^2\s*[+-]\s*\d*(\.\d+)?(?P=var)\s*[+-]\s*\d*(\.\d+)?
```

will accept things in the form of `ax^2 + bx + c`, where a, b and c are floats.

To make it more readable, you can split it like this:

```
var F = $"\d*(\.\d+)?";  //a floating number
var S = $"\s*[+-]\s*";   //+/- sign with leading/trailing space(s)
var Quad = "[+-]?" + F + $"(?<var>\w)\^2" + S + F + $"(?P=var)" + S + F
var Lin = F + $"\w" + S + F + $"\s*=\s*0"
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your expressions `[^2]` is a negated character class that matches any char except a `2`

If you want to match it literally outside the character class you have to escape it `\^` or else its meaning would be an anchor to assert the start of the string.

Using `\w` matches a word character and could also match digits and an underscore. If you want to match a-z you could add that to the character class. Note that you can omit `{1}`.

You might use an optional group `(?:)?` for the first part:

```
(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]\^2 [+-] )?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z] [+-] \d+(?:\.\d+)? = 0
```

That will match:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[+-]?` Optional + or -
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `[a-z]\^2 [+-]` Match char a-z, then `^2` space optional +  or - and space
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z] [+-]` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part, char a-z, space, optional + or - and space
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)? = 0` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part, space = space 0

For example

```
String pattern = @"(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]\^2 [+-] )?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z] [+-] \d+(?:\.\d+)? = 0";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZqu0r/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/yFdVan)

Based on the comment of [dotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137199/dotnet), if the variable should be the same you could use a capturing group with a backreference `\1`. To match both formats you could use an alternation and anchors to assert the start and the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V2opJB/2)

Comment: Quadratic equations require you to have the same variable in `ax^2` and `bx` terms. Using `[a-z]` class is not going to ensure that.

Comment: @dotNET That makes sense, thank you. I might be wrong, but I think your pattern does not match OP's second format.

Comment: *...your pattern does not match OP's second format.* I'd love to fix that, but can't see which pattern you're talking about. `ax + b` should work fine with the `Lin` pattern as far as I can see.

Comment: @dotNET With the second pattern I meant that one indeed but when I test it there is no match [demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4gJrz/1)

Comment: Ah, I was matching `ax + b` only, missing the `= 0` part. Fixed now. And thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern. It may not catch odd situations.

```
([+-]*(\d+x)\^2\s*[+-]\s*)*(\d+x\s*[+-]\s*\d+\s*)=\s*\d+
```

Break it down:

- ([+-]*(\d+x)\^2\s*[+-]\s*)* - first capture group: optional quadratic

  - `[+-]*` - Positive/Negative symbol (`*`) makes it optional
  - `(\d+x)` - `\d+`is one or more digit (number) and `x` is the "x" character. You can replace this with any character or `[a-zA-Z]{1}` for any one letter
  - `\^2` - literal for "^2" (need to escape "^" character)
  - `\s*` - optional space character
  - `[+-]` - either + or -
  - `\s*` - optional space character
  - `*` - makes group optional so it won't fail if it's not there
- (\d+x\s*[+-]\s*\d+\s*) - second capture group: linear piece (required - could add * to end to make optional)

  - `\d+x` - any number followed by "x" (same as first group)
  - `\s*`  - optional space
  - `[+-]` - either + or -
  - `\s*` - optional space
  - `\d+` - last piece of equation (ex: + 5) (required - could wrap in parenthesis and add * to end to make optional)
  - `\s*` - optional space
- =\s*\d+

  - `=` - Equals sign
  - `\s*` - optional space
  - `\d+` - any number after equals sign

** Note: this does not allow decimals or any letter for variable besides x. Currently, only the beginning part of the equation is optional, but this isn't always the case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're hard-coding variable name into regex. Looking at the OP's regex it appears that he is expecting arbitrary variable name there.

Comment: @dotNET You're not wrong. I gave a suggestion of using `[a-zA-Z]{1}` if he is a expecting arbitrary variable name. In his examples and in most math courses, x is the common variable name so I just stuck with that for my regex pattern. I see where you're coming from though.

Comment: It is not just about allowing arbitrary variable name. Thing is that quadratic equations require you to use the same variable in `x^2` and `x` terms. You must use backreferencing to ensure that. See other two answers for an example.